# How to extract ``href`` and ``TEXT`` in the below situation?

Tags: cheerio

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="menu">
   <a class="menu-item" href="........."> TEXT</a>
   <a class="menu-item" href="........."> TEXT</a>
   <a class="menu-item" href="........."> TEXT</a>
   <a class="menu-item" href="........."> TEXT</a>
</div>
```

I am using cheerio for scraping. I want to loop through the anchor tags and extract `TEXT` and `href` but am unable to achieve so.

Please someone guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways to extract 'href' and 'TEXT'

```
const $=cheerio.load(....response data....);
const listItems= $(".menu a");

listItems.each((idx, el)=>{
     const Text= $(el).text();
     const href= $(el).attr("href");
     
     console.log("text"+ text+ "   href" + href);
   

})
```

The line `const listItems= $(".menu a");` is helping to identify the `anchor` tags in `div` and upon looping we can extract the data in the `anchor` using`const Text= $(el).text();` and `const href= $(el).attr("href");`

This is working for me.